# Unable to hover using fire_event and .hover

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

Below is the HTML content. On hovering using watir I need to show the below list which is happening good manually.

```
<li class=" dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ceid="MM - Tour" href="/product-tour">
      Tour 
      <b class="caret"/>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-tour depth-1 row">
      <li class=" col-md-3">
      <li class=" col-md-3">
      <li class=" col-md-3">
      <li class=" col-md-3">
    </ul>
</li>
```

1. on using fire_event "onmouseover", in irb its returning true. But hovering is not performed and the list is not shown. Below is the irb output.

   irb(main):035:0> b.link(:text => 'Tour').present?
   => true
   irb(main):036:0> b.link(:text => 'Tour').fire_event "onmouseover"
   => true
2. On Using .hover, facing the below error.

   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError: Cannot perform native inte raction: Could not load native events component.
           from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/SRIRAM~1/AppData/Local/Temp/webdri ver-profile20140917-6780-x3gs6b/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/dr iver_component.js:9770:3:in `generateErrorForNativeEvents'

Below are my gems versions.

```
watir-webdriver (0.6.10)
selenium-webdriver (2.42.0)

Firefox Browser version : 30.0
```

Is there any other way to perform this mouse hover using watir webdriver?

Regards,
Avinash Duggirala

Comment: Maybe try upgrading your Firefox and Selenium-WebDriver to latest? From the [CHANGES doc](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/rb/CHANGES), there may not have been support for native events in Firefox 30. Selenium 2.42.0 had been updated to support Firefox 29 and Selenium 2.43.0 was supporting native events for Firefox 24, 31 and 32.

Comment: @JustinKo This didn't resolved by problem. I upgraded selenium webdriver to (2.43.0) and my FF to 32  it didn't worked good. Even I tried downgrading the firefox to the version 24, even this combination didnot work out. Any other alternative ??

Comment: @JustinKo I tried with Selenium element = driver.find_element(:css => '#main_menu ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right>li:nth-child(2)>a') driver.action.move_to(element).perform Even this just flashes the overlay for a second. Awaiting your reply from Watir perspective !!

Comment: `driver.action.move_to(element).perform` is exactly what the `hover` method in Watir does. That is why you get the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like when using `hover`, the dropdown becomes visible for a second and then disappears. It seems like the page thinks the mouse is moved to the Tour link and then moved away. Given that the `hover` works in Chrome, I would probably say this is a problem with the Firefox driver.

You can work around the issue by using Javascript to force the dropdown to be displayed - ie changing the display style from "none" to "block":

```
dropdown = b.link(:text => 'Tour').parent.ul
b.execute_script('arguments[0].style.display="block";', dropdown)
```

Comment: The answer is really awesome. Its working perfectly. Thanks a lot Justin